# CryptGenRandom is giving same value while calling in loop

Tags: c++, c, windows, visual-c++

Sorry, I cant use separate class for this and I tried to build following code and getting same output when calling from out side in loop.

```
unsigned int crypt_rand()
{
    HCRYPTPROV hProvider = 0;
    const DWORD dwLength = sizeof(unsigned int);
    unsigned int pbBuffer[dwLength] = {};

    if (!::CryptAcquireContext(&hProvider, 0, 0, PROV_RSA_FULL, CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT | CRYPT_SILENT))
        return 1;
    if (!::CryptGenRandom(hProvider, sizeof(unsigned int), reinterpret_cast<PBYTE>(&pbBuffer)))
    {
        ::CryptReleaseContext(hProvider, 0);
        return 1;
    }
    if (!::CryptReleaseContext(hProvider, 0))
        return 1;
    return (unsigned int)pbBuffer;

}
```

If I am calling this function from loop getting same output every time.Is it anything I can give like input as time in this method.Can you plz help me on this?

```
for (DWORD i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        rand_no = crypt_rand();
        std::cout << "windows::"<<i<<"::"<<rand_no<< std::endl;
    }
```

Output is

```
windows::0::4519964
windows::1::4519964
windows::2::4519964
windows::3::4519964
windows::4::4519964
```

Comment: I suggest you look carefully at what you are returning from `crypt_rand`...

Comment: I am returning entire buffer. my requirement is to get different random values in every call.

Answer (score 4):

The use of casts (the `reinterpret_cast` and the one in the `return` statement) is hiding some important compiler errors that would have allowed you to write this code correctly in the first place.

Avoid the casts as much as you can, fix the types instead.

`CryptGenRandom` expects a

```
BYTE *pbBuffer
```

parameter. Pass it a pointer to an array of `BYTE` *not anything else* (you are passing a pointer to an array of `int`).

In your return statement you are casting an address to `unsigned int`. You need to take the `BYTE` array and convert the *values* it contains to an int (you can find examples of that online or you can make one yourself via sit shifts and additions). What you are doing now is probably outputting the same address (or part of it) over and over again.

To clarify, define your array as

```
BYTE pbBuffer[dwLength] = {};
```

and call your function as

```
::CryptGenRandom(hProvider, dwLength, pbBuffer)
```

Avoid casts, especially the C style casts, and read about arrays. In C++, when passed to a function an array decays to a pointer to the first element of the array. If you have an array of `BYTE` it will decay to a `BYTE*`, the expected type of your function.

Comment: I am not able to use BYTE *pbBuffer in that method which is supporting BYTE. Can you any sample code which I can analyse and try it.

Comment: If I am using BYTE* I am not able to pass as arument in CryptGenRandom(). So can you help how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in `return (unsigned int)pbBuffer;` here you are just getting address of pbBUffer everytime.If pbBuffer is an array and function crypt_rand is returning unsigned int then it should be elements of array at return.

You need to enable warnings during your compilation.These kind of possible errors must be there as warning.

Comment: I need to get one random number for every crypt_rand() call.Can you help me to do that? or can you suggest me how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You want a random number that is an unsigned int?
Just cast the contents of the BYTE buffer to an unsigned int

How about:

```
unsigned int crypt_rand()
{
    HCRYPTPROV hProvider = 0;
    const DWORD dwLength = sizeof(unsigned int);
    BYTE buffer[dwLength];

    if (!::CryptAcquireContext(&hProvider, 0, 0, PROV_RSA_FULL, CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT | CRYPT_SILENT))
        return 1;
    if (!::CryptGenRandom(hProvider, sizeof(buffer), &buffer))
    {
        ::CryptReleaseContext(hProvider, 0);
        return 1;
    }
    if (!::CryptReleaseContext(hProvider, 0))
        return 1;
    return *(unsigned int*)buffer;
}
```